# Looking for direction on building graphical objectsand interacting with them

Tags: user-interface, 3d, wysiwyg

I am looking for guidance and direction to understand how to build and interact with 3D objects either in a browser or client application. For example, websites that show merchandise or objects and allows user to spin them, zoom in/out, change the color or design, etc... I don't know the lingo or definitions to even begin to look.

I'd like to know how I can create a virtual bookshelf and allow users to drag or drop books on the shelves, get the properties on the books, etc... Spin the book shelf, add other attributes to the shelves, like "cardboard cutouts", etc. Any other applicable example is appreciated as well. I do have .Net experience but mostly back-end development experience... looking to expand my horizons.

If someone can point me to some videos, documents, books and include some definitions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Regards,
Bob